# Filter two array of objects and get a resultant array

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I'm trying to check for condition where `carId` in one array is equal to `id` of another array.

Below is the code snippet.

```js
const arr1 = [{
    id: '1',
    type: 'car',
    name: 'BMW',
  },
  {
    id: '2',
    type: 'car',
    name: 'Audi',
  },
  {
    id: '3',
    type: 'car',
    name: 'Benz',
  }
];

const arr2 = [{
  carId: '1'
}, {
  carId: '3'
}];

const result = arr2.map(val => arr2.find(val.carId === id))
console.log(result)
```

The result that I'm expecting is

```
[{
    id: '1',
    type: 'car',
    name: 'BMW',
  },
  {
    id: '3',
    type: 'car',
    name: 'Benz',
  }
];
```

Could anyone please help?

Comment: You want to do result = arr1.filter. Remember filter expects a boolean so just ensure you compare the return value of find with !== undefined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While you should use `.filter()` on `arr1`, and pass a callback to `.find()`, I'd probably first convert `arr2` to a simple list of IDs and use `.includes()` instead.

```js
const arr1 = [{
    id: '1',
    type: 'car',
    name: 'BMW',
  },
  {
    id: '2',
    type: 'car',
    name: 'Audi',
  },
  {
    id: '3',
    type: 'car',
    name: 'Benz',
  }
];

const arr2 = [{
  carId: '1'
}, {
  carId: '3'
}];

const ids = arr2.map(o => o.carId);

const result = arr1.filter(val => ids.includes(val.id))
console.log(result)
```

---

or better yet, convert `arr2` to a `Set`.

```js
const arr1 = [{
    id: '1',
    type: 'car',
    name: 'BMW',
  },
  {
    id: '2',
    type: 'car',
    name: 'Audi',
  },
  {
    id: '3',
    type: 'car',
    name: 'Benz',
  }
];

const arr2 = [{
  carId: '1'
}, {
  carId: '3'
}];

const ids = arr2.map(o => o.carId);
const idSet = new Set(ids);

const result = arr1.filter(val => idSet.has(val.id))
console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
const arr1 = [{
    id: '1',
    type: 'car',
    name: 'BMW',
  },
  {
    id: '2',
    type: 'car',
    name: 'Audi',
  },
  {
    id: '3',
    type: 'car',
    name: 'Benz',
  }
];

const arr2 = [{
  carId: '1'
}, {
  carId: '3'
}];

const result = arr1.filter(a1val => arr2.find(a2val => a2val.carId === a1val.id) !== undefined);
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work

```
const result = arr2.map(val => arr1.find(item => item.id === val.carId))
```